# CPU Currently used on c++

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder

How can I print out current CPU usage using C++? I tried to compile the following code in C++Builder:

```
static PDH_HQUERY cpuQuery;
static PDH_HCOUNTER cpuTotal;    

void init(){
    PdhOpenQuery(NULL, NULL, &cpuQuery);
    PdhAddCounter(cpuQuery, TEXT("\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time", NULL, &cpuTotal);
    PdhCollectQueryData(cpuQuery);
}    

double getCurrentValue(){
    PDH_FMT_COUNTERVALUE counterVal;    

    PdhCollectQueryData(cpuQuery);
    PdhGetFormattedCounterValue(cpuTotal, PDH_FMT_DOUBLE, NULL, &counterVal);
    Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add(String(counterVal.doubleValue));
    return counterVal.doubleValue;
}
```

But I am getting the wrong answer (3.124564654E-304).  If I change `TEXT("\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time", NULL, &cpuTotal);` to `("\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time", NULL, &cpuTotal);` I get the correct answer (0).

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: You aren't doing any error checking. Why not?

Comment: The code you have shown should not even compile, as you are missing a closing `)` on the `TEXT()` macro, that line should be: `PdhAddCounter(cpuQuery, TEXT("\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time"), NULL, &cpuTotal);
    `

Answer (score 2):

The obvious question would be how busy you're keeping the CPU between the time you initialize the query and the time you display the result.

Doing a quick test, I seem to be getting reasonable results.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <atomic>
#include "pdh.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "pdh.lib")

class Query {

    PDH_HQUERY cpuQuery;
    PDH_HCOUNTER cpuTotal;
public:
    Query() {
        PdhOpenQuery(NULL, NULL, &cpuQuery);
        PdhAddCounter(cpuQuery, TEXT("\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time"), NULL, &cpuTotal);
        PdhCollectQueryData(cpuQuery);
    }

    operator double() {
        PDH_FMT_COUNTERVALUE counterVal;

        PdhCollectQueryData(cpuQuery);
        PdhGetFormattedCounterValue(cpuTotal, PDH_FMT_DOUBLE, NULL, &counterVal);
        return counterVal.doubleValue;
    }
};

int main() {
    Query q;

    // First try a couple of seconds of relative quiescent:
    Sleep(2000);

    std::cout << q << "\n";

    // Then a little while keeping the CPU busy:
    volatile unsigned long long k=0;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:k)
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
            ++k;

    std::cout << q << "\n";
}
```

I compiled (with VC++) with OpenMP enabled like this:

```
cl /O2b2 /GL /openmp test.cpp
```

...and got the following results:

```
3.28491
98.9863
```

So, roughly 3% CPU usage when I left the system idle, and 99% when I kept it busy. I suppose you could argue that the latter should really be a little closer to 100%, but at least to me the results still seem fairly reasonable.